# Angular Date Filter not showing UTC ..!

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datefilter

When I do this `{{1288323623006 | date:'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z'}}` I am getting:

```
2010-10-29 09:10:23 +0530.
```

But I want `2010-10-29 09:10:23 IST`. 
How  can I do this with the angular date filter?

My aim is to show the timezone`[IST,EST]` instead of a number like `+0530 or -0400`

Comment: @deceze thanks for the comment, my issue is with displaying the  timezone, functionality wise it is working fine. But i want to show IST or EST according to the zones.

Comment: Is there any alternative for this ?

Comment: hi @DanielBeck i have used moment.JS but still i am unable to get timezone like EST,IST etc..!check this plunker. http://plnkr.co/edit/FByfpJYQJVxjDzhzH8Js?p=preview

Comment: http://momentjs.com/timezone/ (but note that times are by default handled relative to the end user's timezone, not yours or your server's. If you're trying to force a particular zone to display, test from different receiving zones to ensure that you're not introducing offset errors.)

Comment: @Deniel Beck, thanks for the comment..! Is there anyway i can make my milliseconds to display only EST time? So that i can hard code EST beside it..!

Comment: Thank you @DanielBeck I did not get what i wanted but i found the other way..!  http://plnkr.co/edit/FByfpJYQJVxjDzhzH8Js?p=preview